# Accessing data from tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to reference a column from another table in my rails application. I want to reference the site_name using the matching site_id columns from both tables(sites and trials).

My controller

```
def list
 @list = Trial.year(params[:year]).order(:region_id)
end
```

My Models

```
class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :trial_id, :site_id, :year, :trial_type, :region_id

  scope :year, ->(year) { where(year: year) }
  scope :trial_id, ->(trial_id) { where(trial_id: trial_id) }

  belongs_to :site

end


class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :site_id, :site_name, :region

  has_many :trials

end
```

My View

```
<table class="table">
    <th>Trial Location</th>
    <th>Trial Type</th>
    <th>Grower</th>
    <% @list.each do |list| %>
    <tr>
    <td>
  <%= link_to list.site.site_name, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) %>
    </td>
    <td>    
    <%= link_to list.trial_type, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) unless list.trial_type.blank? %>
    </td>
    <td>    
    <%= link_to list.trial_type, trial_trials_path(trial_id: list.trial_id) unless list.trial_type.blank? %>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do both the sites table and trials table have `site_id`? I would expect `trials` to have `site_id` and `sites` to have a primary key `id` column

Comment: Thanks Ryan, you lead me in the right direction. I used a customer primary key: belongs_to :site, :primary_key => 'site_id' and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the association in your model does write the getter method for you.  The attr_accessibles sets up that method.

Add :site to your Trial's attr_accessible